# Minimizing the Height of a Binary Search Tree

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, binary-tree

If I am attempting to minimize the height of a Binary Search Tree, are these the correct steps?:

1) produce a sorted array from the tree
2) reconstruct the tree by adding the sorted elements into the tree inorder

Comment: What do you mean by step 3? Obviously, ensuring that a tree is balanced solves the problem, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After sorting the elements, you rebuild the tree by defining the middle element to be the root node, and then recursively build the left and right subtrees from the elements preceding and following the middle, respectively.

Comment: You can achieve this with a merge-sort like approach. At each step, pick the middle element (say `m`) of the original sorted array, build the sub-trees for the left and right portions of the array (say `lt` and `rt`) and make a new sub-tree with `m` as the root and `lt` & `rt` on either side. The recursion bottoms-up when the array length is `<= 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an already sorted list to a simple non-balancing binary search tree will build the theoretical Worst case for a binary search tree.  The lowest-valued node is the root, every node is added to the 'right' of the node immediately preceding it in the list, and you create a tree of maximum depth, searching in O(n) time rather than O(lg n).  You'dd effectively just be building an overly complicated linked-list.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you reconstruct the tree structure before you try to insert sorted elements via `inorder`, the solution you provide will be right.

1. Reconstruct the tree. just like a heap.
2. Insert sorted element via inorder

For example, if the original tree is like this:

```
                 (5)
           (3)         (6)
      (2)      (4)
  (1)
```

1. Reconstruct the tree like this:

   ```
              ()
       ()            ()
   ()      ()   ()
   ```
2. Insert sorted element via `inorder`: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

   ```
               (4)
        (2)             (6)
   (1)      (3)    (5)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have access to the tree and can alter it "manually". I think your balancing problem could be solved like this (pseudocode):

```
depth(node)
{
    if node is null, return 0;
    l = depth(left child);
    r = depth(right child);
    diff = (r - l);
    if (diff < -1) rotate right (as often as you need);
    else if (diff > 1) rotate left (as often as you need);
    return the new maximum depth of both subtrees +1;
}
```

I must confess, I am not very sure about this, but the idea is that you don't need the temporary array, because traversing the tree and applying the right rotations should do.